# How do I show an admop interstitial ad after number of clicks on the item-views of recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In some apps that are similar to my app, they have this thing when the user clicks on the item views of the recycler view randomly for 3 or 4 times and it displays an Admob interstitial ad for them before moving to the next activity or fragment. I would like to do the same, like showing the ad for the user after he clicks randomly for 3 or 4 times on the item views and when the ad is closed it should move to the next fragment. How do I do this kind of idea?

P.C. I am using navigation components to navigate between the fragments and you can use java or kotlin, I understand them both.

**Here is my recycler view code **

```
    class NewsListAdapter(
    val context: Context,
    val news_list: ArrayList<NewsListViewModel>,
    val view: View
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsListAdapter.vHolder>() {


    var inum = 1
    var countNum = 0
    private lateinit var OverLoad: OverLoad
    private lateinit var mRef: DatabaseReference

    private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    private final var TAG = "NewsListAdapter"


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): vHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.news_list_design, parent, false)

        return vHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return news_list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: vHolder, position: Int) {

        val newsList = news_list[position]

        val image = newsList!!.image
        val imageView = holder.news_image

        Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(image)
            .into(imageView)
        holder.news_title.text = newsList.title
        holder.news_desc.text = newsList.desc
        holder.news_date.text = newsList.date
        holder.news_type.text = newsList.type


        val shared = context.getSharedPreferences("LatestNewsSaving", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = shared.edit()

        editor.putInt("fav_blue", R.drawable.ic_favorite_blue)
        editor.putInt("fav_border", R.drawable.ic_favorite_border)
        // editor.putInt("count_newsList_num", countNum)
        editor.apply()


        interstitialAd()

        PushDownAnim.setPushDownAnimTo(holder.card_view)

            .setOnClickListener {

                countNum += 1
                editor.putInt("count_newsList_num", countNum)
                editor.apply()

                if (shared.getInt("count_newsList_num", 0) == 3) {
                    countNum = 0

                    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                        mInterstitialAd?.show(context as Activity)
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
                    }

                    val passData = LatestNewsFragmentDirections
                        .actionLatestNewsFragmentToNewsDetailFragment(news_list[position])
                    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(passData)
                } else {
                    val passData = LatestNewsFragmentDirections
                        .actionLatestNewsFragmentToNewsDetailFragment(news_list[position])
                    Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(passData)
                }


            }
    }

    fun interstitialAd() {

        var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        InterstitialAd.load(context, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", adRequest, object :
            InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
            }
        })
    }

    class vHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val news_image = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.news_image)
        val news_title = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.news_title)
        val news_desc = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.news_desc)
        val news_date = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.news_date)
        val news_type = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.news_type)

        val card_view = view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.newsListCard)
        val favourite_add = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.favourites_add)


    }

}
```

Comment: You have code that runs an ad every 3 clicks on your `RecyclerView` already, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @AliasCartellano the code doesn't work no matter how many times I click it

Comment: Not related to your question, but the fact that you're storing drawable IDs to shared preferences is a big code smell. I can't imagine what you're doing with them, but you should be aware that those IDs are not stable from build to build.

Comment: I would not put the interstitial ad code inside this adapter. Leave that in the Activity. If you want the activity to show an ad, expose a callback for the Activity to do it in. Right now, you are loading a new ad every time another view holder gets bound, so you're loading many ads in parallel. It's likely the ad network will not behave well if you do that, and it's also wasting bandwidth and resources. It might be that loading additional ads drops the previously-loaded ads. You also might get throttled for requesting so many, and it's likely your most recent request will receive nothing.

Comment: Also, I hope you haven't shared your secret key in the code above...If you have, you should go to the ad network site and destroy it and create a new one.

Comment: @Tenfour04  As I said on my question, I am using a single activity app so most of the pages are actually Fragments and by using navigation components I can navigate between the pages. About the drawable IDs I was actually trying some stuff and ideas, I will delete them soon

Comment: Just exchange the word Fragment for Activity in my advice above.

Comment: why you call  interstitialAd() in direct onBind() ? onBind() is called for every item on the list. so you send a lot of requests on a server every second. you should achieve using simple int variable like count and call only when your condition is true in onItemClicklistener